# Django: Admin register decorator for custom admin site class

Tags: django, django-admin

So I want to customize the admin page using the AdminSite class as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-adminsite).

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from .models import MyModel

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = 'Monty Python administration'

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadmin')
```

But instead of using `admin_site.register(MyModel)` I would like to use the register decorator like

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin

@admin_site.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

However, this only throws the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Is there now register decorator for subclasses of `AdminSite` in Django yet (1.9) or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the keyword argument `site` like this:

@admin.register(MyModel, **site=MyAdminSite**)

```
from django.contrib import admin
...

@admin.register(MyModel, site=MyAdminSite)
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Docs on the register decorator:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator

Comment: It's actually `@admin.register(MyModel, site=admin_site)`

Comment: You can also use partial from functools and do:
`myadmin_register = partial(admin.register, site=admin_site)`
Then you can use the @myadmin_register decorator with just `@myadmin(MyModel)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have figured it out yet. But I see that you haven't subclassing `admin.ModelAdmin` in your admin class.

```
@admin_site.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: Well I did. I just imported like `from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    ...

admin_site = MyAdminSite()

@admin_site.register(MyModel)
def ...
```

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` is caused by the fact that `admin_site.register` is calling method `register` of `AdminSite`.

You should use [django.contrib.admin.register](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator) which is the correct decorator:

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(MyModel, site=admin_site)
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    ...
```